# Inquiry about jbpm to support springboot 3. x

Tags: jbpm

We are currently facing a pivotal challenge as we are in the process of upgrading our projects from Spring Boot 2 to Spring Boot 3.x. This upgrade is crucial for us to take advantage of the latest features, improvements, and security enhancements offered by Spring Boot 3.x. However, we are concerned about the compatibility and support of jBPM with Spring Boot 3.x, as this integration is critical to the smooth functioning of our applications.

Given the importance of jBPM in our project architecture, we are keen to understand if there are any plans from the jBPM team to officially support Spring Boot 3.x. Specifically, we would greatly appreciate it if you could share:

- Whether there is an existing roadmap or plan for jBPM to support Spring Boot 3.x.
- Any important milestones or dates for when we might expect this support to be available, if plans are indeed in place.